# Find the value of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> Find the value of $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

I tried expressing the sum like $\sum a_r-a_{r-1}$.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)-\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$

I got stuck here. Is there any other simpler method?

Comment: Would you know how to deal with $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \log\left(n-1\right)-\log n - (\log n - \log(n+1) ) \right)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

The last sum is telescopic.

Answer (score 2):

substitute the value of n from 2 and see all terms cancel out and some term will remain then let the n go to infinity and you will get an approx. answer.